# Get htaccess rewritten URL with jquery

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

I'm currently using a .htaccess file and it's something like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ page.php?link=$1&sublink=$2`

All I can get is the URL the way it is displayed but I can't see to find a way to return to me what the `.htaccess` is masking.

I used this to solve part of my problems

```
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] === 'link') {
        $('a[href*="' + sParameterName[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

This code returns what I need if the URL isn't friendly, but only in that case. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: jQuery/javascript only has access to the current URL, not whatever redirects was done on the serverside ?

Comment: The more I know, the better.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass it as a parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(/?)$ page.php?link=$1&sublink=$2&original=$1/$2$3
```

Comment: I could try something like that, but all the pages differ from one another. This is only one of the exemples I'm using. I would have to change my whole htaccess to fit to what I need with JS

Comment: There's no way to see what the original request was before the rewrite, unless you pass it to your script somehow.

Comment: I'll try something doable as soon as I redefine the pages now. Thanks anyway